# from chrome, i want to launch google in IE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shell

**I Want to:** from `chrome` i want to launch google.com in `IE`.

**Issue:** when i run in chrome, google doesnt open. but if i am using IE, than google open up in IE

```
    <Script>
        function openURL(){
            var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            shell.run("iexplore http://google.com");
        }  
     </Script>

    <a onclick="openURL()" href=""> test </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this works in Internet Explorer (IE) and not Chrome is because `ActiveXObject` is not a web standard, and is only supported by IE. What you're asking for is unfortunately not possible at this time.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. i will looking into some other way to open IE from chrome

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for you then you could create a custom protocol to open up internet explorer like you can do with the windows 10 calculator `Calculator://`

Then you would be able to launch it in plain html

```html
<a href="yourprotocolname://">Open Internet Explorer</a>
```

Calculator example:

```html
<a href="Calculator://">Open Calculator</a>
```

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols

You may also want to take a argument as a website to open somehow